# Определенный интеграл методом  Симпсона

Tags: java, численные-методы

Как найти определенный интеграл методом Симпсона от 1 до (е) ((x*ln(x))^2)dx? Количество разбиений 52. шаг вычислений первообразной (е-1)/8. **точность 0,001**. Вернее подскажите, как можно проверить его на точность? Вот моя реализация:

```
  public double f(double x){
     return Math.pow(x*Math.log(x), 2);
  }

  public double Integral(int n, double a, double b){
    double sum=0,sum2=0;
     double[] x=new double[n];
     double h=(b-a)/n;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        x[i]=a+i*h;
    }
     for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
         sum+=f(x[i]);
        sum2+=f((x[i-1]+x[i])/2);
     }
     return h/6*(f(a)+f(b)+2*sum+4*(sum2+b));
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Simpson s=new Simpson();
     System.out.println(s.Integral(52,1, Math.E));
 }
```

Comment: `Math.pow(xMath.log(x), 2)` - не пишите так, `pow` считается через `exp` от `log`, лучше через временную переменную пишите `y=xMath.log(x); return y*y;`

Массив здесь вообще не нужен

Comment: спасибо, исправлю) а на счет точности не подскажете?

Comment: вот вроде есть формулы http://www.cleverstudents.ru/method_of_parabolas.html

Comment: по идее надо добавить? : 
        t=Math.abs((sum-sum2)/3);
       
        while(t>0.001);
        return t;
        }
только почему при этом ответ выводит 2.8346697378812106E-4? Это нормально?

Comment: Что за странная формула? зачем while? Количество отрезков разбиения задано. "Шаг вычислений первообразной (е-1)/8" - вот это мне не понятно, если n=52, то почему на 8 делить?

Comment: кстати интеграл берущийся

Answer (score 1):

Для метода симпсона необходимо делать оценку рунге

```
Math.Abs(I1 - I2)/15 > eps
```

I1 - результат на предыдущем подсчете.
I2 - результат на текущем подсчете.
15 берется по формуле 2^O - 1, где О это порядок сложности, у симпсона он равен 4.